# What will be nth term of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let **a, a+d, a+2d,....,** be an A.P.If we eliminate every *pth* term, then what will be the new general value of nth term?

For e.g. Let the A.P. be **2,5,8, *11* ,14,17,20, *23* ,26,29...**[a=2, d=3] Now, if we eliminate every 4th term, the new A.P. will be **2,5,8,14,17,20,26, 29...**.
What will be general formula for nth term of this new progression and in general, what will be the nth term of a general A.P(**a, a+d, a+2d...**)?

Comment: The general term of an A.P. is $$a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$$ with $\;d=$ the constant difference.

Comment: $a_n = a_0 + \left\lfloor \frac{p+1}{p} n \right\rfloor d$

Answer (score 1):

The previous formula for the $m$'th term was  was $a+(m-1)d$.

We shall establish how many numbers we have skipped. to do this write your number $n$ as $3l+r$ with $r$ being $1,2$ or $3$.

Then the number on the original sequence you want is $n+l$

thus the new formula is $a+(n+l-1)3$

Comment: I can't understand your answer

Comment: what part don't you understand?

Comment: what's k? Can you show an example?

Comment: it should be a $3$

Answer (score 0):

Your new progression is given by a reccurence relation

$
y_{n+3}-y_{n}=12
$

with $y_1=2$, $y_2=5$ and $y_3=8$. It is not hard to show that the general formula for the sequence is

$
y_n=4n-3+\frac 1{\sqrt 3}\cdot\sin\left(\frac 23\pi n\right)-\cos\left(\frac 23\pi n\right)
$